# About video communication

Tags: .net, video, video-streaming, h.264, vp8

I'm a .Net developer who developing mvc web and wpf application. I'm currently working on a contact center project. I've build sip endpoint and many desktop application for them. So for our new project we need to develop some video conference application for their customer. 
 I've never done before development related with video conf stuff. As they said they send me http request to our server and i'll get what i need for. It's ok for now, but they using h.263 and h.264 video codecs for video. I'd used some sdk for sip endpoint. On that sdk (on reference manual) it says support for VP8 video codec. I didn't quite understand that.
 Should i add codec feature for h.264 for communicate (and how can i)? On customer site how can they see our customer representative ? 
 I really digging for this, i know about voice no problem for me. But voice is new for me and i didn't get a entry point for this kind of development. Can anyone light my way ?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not aware of any standard codec called v8. Do you mean vp8?

Comment: yes vp8, sorry for misspelling.